# PowerShell to Batch Script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Can you please help me convert the below PowerShell Script to Batch File? I have Systems they don't have PowerShell. Please Help.

```
$inst = (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
'Host Name: '+$env:COMPUTERNAME
foreach ($i in $inst)
{
'SQL Server Instance Name: '+$i
 $p = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL').$i
(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Edition
(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Version
}
```

**Conversion Below**

```
@echo off 
echo %COMPUTERNAME%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,3 delims= " %%S in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"') do ( 
SET "COREEDITION=%%~S" 
SET "COREVERSION=%%~T"
SET "KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\!COREVERSION!\Setup" 
SET "VALUE_NAME=Edition"
echo Instance Name : !COREVERSION!  
rem echo EDITION 
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%E in ('reg query "!KEY_NAME!" /v !VALUE_NAME!') do echo Edition: %%E 
SET VALUES_NAME=Version 
rem echo VERSION
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%V in ('reg query "!KEY_NAME!" /v !VALUES_NAME!') do echo Version: %%V 
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Can you please whack whoever wrote this PowerShell script over the head with a blunt implement? Changing the execution policy from a script (temporarily even) is not only a bad idea (it's a global setting, after all), it won't even work because the script would have to be running for the check, which means that scripts are allowed to run in any case.

Comment: Thats true I have removed it ... Thanks

Comment: Replace the systems that don't have PowerShell. PowerShell v2 works all the way back to Windows XP SP3 & Windows Server 2003. Anything older than that needs to be replaced on the basis of barely supported by MS (both in Extended Support mode now)

Answer (score 1):

in case you have REG.EXE (home editions of windows come without reg.exe)

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,3 delims= " %%S in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"') do (
  echo EDITION: %%S
  echo VERSION: %%T
)
```

**update**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,3 delims= " %%S in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"') do ( 
 SET "COREEDITION=%%~S" 
 SET "COREVERSION=%%~T"
 SET "KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\!COREVERSION!\Setup" 
 SET "VALUE_NAME=Edition"
 rem echo EDITION 
 for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%E in ('reg query "!KEY_NAME!" /v !VALUE_NAME!') do echo edition: %%E 
 SET VALUES_NAME=Version 
 rem echo VERSION
 for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%V in ('reg query "!KEY_NAME!" /v !VALUES_NAME!') do echo edition: %%V 
)

endlocal
```

Comment: @echo off

    for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,3 delims= " %%S in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"') do (
   SET COREEDITION=%%S
   SET COREVERSION=%%T

   SET KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\%COREVERSION%\Setup

   SET VALUE_NAME=Edition
   REM echo EDITION
   reg query "%KEY_NAME%" /v %VALUE_NAME%

   SET VALUES_NAME=Version
   echo VERSION
   reg query "%KEY_NAME%" /v %VALUES_NAME%
   )

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I am trying to get the Version and Edition of each SQL Installed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
function ConvertTo-Batch
{ # file names can be passed per parameter or pipeline
param([Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)][Alias("FullName")]$Path)



BEGIN
{ # initialize counter
$COUNTCONVERTED = 0
}



PROCESS
{ # found more than one object
if ($Path -is [System.Array])
{ # call for each object
foreach ($File in $Path) { ConvertTo-Batch $File }
# and exit function
return
}



if (Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Leaf)
{ # file found, check extension
if ([IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path) -eq ".ps1")
{ # convert only Powershell scripts
$CONTENT = "function CTB_{"
$CONTENT += Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw -Encoding UTF8
$CONTENT += "`n};_CT_B_ $ENV:1 $ENV:2 $ENV:3 $ENV:4 $ENV:5 $ENV:6 $ENV:7 $ENV:8 $ENV:9"
$ENCODED = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($CONTENT))
$NEWPATH = [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($Path, ".bat")
"@echo off`nsetlocal`nset 1=%1`nset 2=%2`nset 3=%3`nset 4=%4`nset 5=%5`nset 6=%6`nset 7=%7`nset 8=%8`nset 9=%~9`npowershell.exe -NOP -EP ByPass -Enc $ENCODED" | Set-Content -Path $NEWPATH -Encoding ASCII
$COUNTCONVERTED++
Write-Output "Converted $Path`: $NEWPATH written."
}
else
{ # other file type
Write-Output "$Path is no Powershell script."
}
}
else
{ # it is a directory or the file does not exist
Write-Output "$Path is a directory or does not exist."
}
}



END
{ # report count of converted files
Write-Output "$COUNTCONVERTED files converted."
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).